# Faster way to authenticate Congnito JWT token using JAVA

Tags: java, performance, jwt

I am currrently doing the following

```
String region = "us-east-1";
String poolID = "us-east-1_whatever";

public Boolean valid() {
    try {
        String cognitoUrl = String.format("https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com/%s/.well-known/jwks.json", region, poolID);
        JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(cognitoUrl));
        // got the value from the cognito url
        Jwk jwk = provider.get("value");
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, null);
        String iss = String.format("https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com/%s", region, poolID);
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer(iss).build();
        verifier.verify(token);

    } catch (Exception err) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but it seems very laggy. how can i verify the token faster?
I am using

```
compile group: 'com.auth0', name: 'jwks-rsa', version: '0.3.0'
compile 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.8.1'
```

Comment: Is it necessary to get the jwk everytime from that url? How about caching it locally and only renew it, when the verification of the signature fails?

Comment: @jps thats exactly what I am looking for. 
I thought there was something on the auth0 library that would help me here.

Comment: I am not used to jwk. Can I just copy the values? dont they change every so often?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon recommends using the Well Known JWKS URL every time, as mentioned in their [Support Repository](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/blob/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt/decode-verify-jwt.py).

Caching is not a recommended practice, as the value is subjected to change. Hence, I would recommend continuing your current approach to ensure the same functionality with the best security.

Comment: `Jwk jwk = provider.get("value")` but here i am still hard coding the 'kid' value here. Is this the right approach?